# View over GLSurfaceView flickers or is not displayed at all

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

We use a `ViewGroup` containing a large `GLSurfaceView` and a small View. The View is drawn on top of the `GLSurfaceView`. The View is visible while being dragged but it disappears as soon as the movement ends and the finger is released from the tablet. We found this happening only in case that `setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)` is set. It works when the image is rendered continuously but that has pretty bad performance implications.

When using a `RelativeLayout` instead of a ViewGroup the View is displayed after the finger is released from the tablet, but it flickers when the View is moved slowly.

It's not possible to draw the View with OpenGL, because the `GLSurfaceView` doesn't fill to whole ViewGroup and the View can be moved all over the ViewGroup.

Here is a complete sample, that shows the problem:

```
package test.gl.app;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class GLTestAppActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLViewGroup = new GLViewGroup(this);
        setContentView(mGLViewGroup);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLViewGroup.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLViewGroup.onResume();
    }

    private GLViewGroup mGLViewGroup;
}



class ImageView extends View {

    private Drawable _drawable;

    public ImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _drawable = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_192));
        _drawable.setBounds(0,0,_drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),_drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        measure(0,0);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int m, int m2) {
        setMeasuredDimension(_drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), _drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }

    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
        _drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}



class GLViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

    private ClearGLSurfaceView mGLView;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private int mX = 300;
    private int mY = 200;

    public GLViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mGLView = new ClearGLSurfaceView(context);
        addView(mGLView);

        mImageView = new ImageView(context);
        addView(mImageView);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                mX = (int)event.getX();
                mY = (int)event.getY();

                mImageView.layout(mX, mY, mX+mImageView.getMeasuredWidth(), mY+mImageView.getMeasuredHeight());

                mGLView.setColor(event);
                if (mGLView.getRenderMode()==GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)
                    mGLView.requestRender();

                return true;
            }
        });

        measure(0, 0);
    }

    public void onResume() {
       mGLView.onResume();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        debug(0);
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        mGLView.layout(l, t, r, b);
        mImageView.layout(mX, mY, mX+mImageView.getMeasuredWidth(), mY+mImageView.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
}


class ClearGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public ClearGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mRenderer = new ClearRenderer();
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);                       // <- remove this line and it works, but app is slow
        measure(0, 0);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
        setColor(event);
        return false;
    }

    public void setColor(final MotionEvent event) {
        queueEvent(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                mRenderer.setColor(event.getX() / getWidth(),
                        event.getY() / getHeight(), 1.0f);
            }});
    }

    private ClearRenderer mRenderer;
}



class ClearRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(mRed, mGreen, mBlue, 1.0f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void setColor(float r, float g, float b) {
        mRed = r;
        mGreen = g;
        mBlue = b;
    }

    private float mRed   = 0.5f;
    private float mGreen = 0.5f;
    private float mBlue  = 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: we added `mImageView.requestLayout();` at the end of `onTouch()` and now it works fine.

Comment: Calling requestLayout() on the offending imageView worked for me.